# WordPress post featured image background header behind logo

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would try to make the featured image as background header behind the logo but the result is not show the image only this string:

```
">
```

So I think something wrong with the code, but I don't know what.

Here is my code:

```
   <?php else: ?>
     <div id="header-video">
      <div id="video_bg" class="img_full_responsive" style="width:100%;background:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'image-featured'); ?> ">
 <?php  include(TEMPLATEPATH."/template/header/header-logo.php"); ?>
     </div>
   </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: Check `$post_id` is correct for a page ?

Comment: Are you using a custom field for the "image-featured"? If you're using WP's default featured image you should be using "the_post_thumbnail_url", more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_thumbnail_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );

<div id="video_bg" class="img_full_responsive" style="width:100%;background:url('<?php echo echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?> ">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/header/header-logo.php">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the Site:

https://www.grenzenlostour.de/reiseberichte/asien/kazakhstan/die-steppe-und-die-suche-nach-schatten/

i want the same as on the index site with the video, featured image the behaind the logo. her the full Code:

```
 <?php if(is_home()): ?>
  <div id="header-video">
<div id="video_bg" style="width:100%;background:url('<?php echo esc_url($ilgelo_options['ilgelo-video-image']['url']); ?>');"
 data-vide-bg="mp4: <?php echo  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-video-mp4']['url']);?>,
  webm: <?php echo  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-video-webm']['url']);?>,
  ogv: <?php echo  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-video-ogv']['url']);?>,
  poster: <?php echo  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-video-image']['url']);?>"
 data-vide-options="position: 0% 50%">

    <!--<span class="section_mask" style="background-color: <?php echo  $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-color-video-mask']?>; opacity: <?php echo  $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-opacity-video-mask']?>;"></span>-->

     <?php  include(TEMPLATEPATH."/template/header/header-logo.php"); ?>

</div>
</div>
 <?php else: ?>
<div id="header-video">

<div id="video_bg" class="img_full_responsive" style="width:100%; background:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'image-featured'); ?> ">
 <?php  include(TEMPLATEPATH."/template/header/header-logo.php"); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
```